# Kubernetes pulls image every time pod restarts

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, devops

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy):

> Always
>
> every time the kubelet launches a container, the kubelet queries the container image registry to resolve the name to an image digest. If the kubelet has a container image with that exact digest cached locally, the kubelet uses its cached image; otherwise, the kubelet pulls the image with the resolved digest, and uses that image to launch the container.

Despite that, `kubectl describe pod` shows that the image is being pulled from the registry even though the image is present on the worker node (`crictl images`) and the pod runs normally with `IfNotPresent` or `Never` without re-downloading the image. How is this possible?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but image management, which makes it off-topic here. --- How is the question related to docker? --- I do not understand the question. `Always` queries the external registry always for the digest of a tag, even if an image with a tag is cached. `IfNotPresent` only queries when an image with the tag is not cached. `Never` never queries the external registry.

Comment: @Turing85 Should I move or copy the question to Superuser? --- I guess because I'm using Docker Hub, whose pull limit caused me to discover this problem . --- If I use ```IfNotPresent``` or ```Never``` and the image is already downloaded (whether pulled manually or automatically), k8s uses the local image. With, ```Always```, the image is re-pulled every time the pod restarts.

Comment: your question - your decision.

Comment: @Turing85 Also re: off-topic, when you send feedback at the bottom of the documentation page, it directs you to Stack Overflow. Thought that was pretty funny.

Comment: Huh interesting... thanks for the information.